# How can I remove inline JS/CSS added by WordPress plugins?

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

My WordPress site uses a number of plugins that add arbitrary JavaScript and CSS inline into the body of my pages. How can I intercept it, and move them all to a combined external file, or at least to the bottom of the page?

Comment: Well, not so simple, since they're added via WP plugins. I'm thinking something akin to the `wp_dequeue_style( 'stylesheet-handle' );` function, since when you update the plugin, your changes would get overridden again.

Comment: contact the plugin developer(s)

Comment: Lots of plugin developers do this; it's really bad form and makes the pages load more slowly. Is there a catch-all way?